# Communicate with a smart plug from my own JSON server directely

Tags: smart-plugs, rest-api

I am new to the field of IoT, I am very grateful for your help. My goal is to turn on/off and obtain the state a smart plug via my own JSON server not using its manufacturer's API.

Please if you have any suggestion of a smart plug that I can add or modify or integrate with my own server to communicate with my plug.
I considered creating a python script running on a Raspberry Pi that receives commands from my own server and sends the command to the manufacturer's API. Is there any other solution? A way to integrate directly my own API server to the smart plug?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I have edited your question in an attempt to clarify the grammar; please feel free to [edit] if I have altered the intention of the post or to roll back my edits.  Also, you can earn your first badge by taking the [tour], you can also get more details on how this site works in the [help].  Welcome aboard!

Comment: @Jean we don't know where you're from or what smart plugs are available in your area of the world. I would recommend looking online at a shopping site and seeing what smart plugs are available. Pick three or four that look appealing. Then research them online and find ones that have a publicly available API, and you'll be set.